# Moving from SKScene to ViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I want to move from my `SKScene` to a view controller when I touch a `SKSpriteNode` and back to `SKScene` when I touch a `UIButton`. It is working from view controller to `SKScene` and also the other way around, but only the first time. When I then go back to my scene and the move to the view controller again (the second time), I can hear the music, and it prints everything from `viewDidLoad`, but it does not the show me UI Elements. I dismissed the scene so that might not be the problem.

Here is the code for moving back from the scene to the view controller.

```
let currentViewController:UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!        
currentViewController.present(ViewController(), animated: false, completion: nil)
```

or

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"VC")
let currentViewController:UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!

currentViewController.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the code related to `currentViewController` with this:

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It should work.
You can also create a `segue` in `Storyboard` and call it like this:

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "VC", sender: self)
```

EDIT:

I've tried on one of my app now the next solution and it worked:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC")
vc.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations:
        {
        window.rootViewController = vc
    }, completion: { completed in
        // maybe do something here
    })
```

To me it worked, I hope it will solve your case :)

Comment: I have the same problem again, it is still working one time. But the second time it is calling the function viewdidload of my viewcontroller again but i don't see any UI Elements.

Comment: Happy it worked. mark this answer as the solution so others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

**New solution:**

Let's say you have a view controller file called "GameViewController" linked with file called "GameScene".
Problem: You want to move to "NextViewController" from "GameScene".

Follow the steps carefully:

1. In the storyboard create a manual segue relationship from "GameViewController" screen to "NextViewController" choose for example "Show"
2. In the Attributes Inspector: assign an identifier (e.g. "ShowNext"), a class (e.g. "ShowSegue"), and module using the drop-down menu.
3. In the "GameViewController" create a class named "ShowSegue" as shown and make sure you import UIKit and SpriteKit:

```
class ShowSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
   override func perform() {
       source.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
   }
}
```

4. In the GameViewController class inside the "viewDidLoad()" function add the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = GameScene(size : view.bounds.size) // <- GameScene
    scene.sceneDelegate = self // <- must add this
    let skView = view as! SKView
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

5. In the "GameScene" file add this code at the top making sure you import SpriteKit:

```
protocol GameSceneDelegate: AnyObject {
    func presentNextViewController()
}

class DelegateWrapper {
    weak var delegate: GameSceneDelegate?
}

struct SharedInstances {
    static let delegateWrapper = DelegateWrapper()
}
```

6. in the didMove() function of the "GameScene" class add:

```
SharedInstances.delegateWrapper.delegate = sceneDelegate
```

6. In the function where you trigger the button press add the code:

```
SharedInstances.delegateWrapper.delegate?.presentNextViewController()
```

Change the names of the variables according to your needs.